# ld: can not find -lwiretap. Why & how can I make it available

Tags: c++, perl, makefile

Already installed wireshark in my linux box, also able to create makefile; but when I try to make it. It gives error like-

```
$make
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so
cc  -shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector Wtap.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so    \
       -L/usr/lib/wireshark -lwiretap   \

/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so] Error 1
```

also, sudo does not resolve error

```
$sudo make
chmod 644 Wtap.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so
cc  -shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector Wtap.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so    \
       -L/usr/lib/wireshark -lwiretap   \

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwiretap
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Wtap/Wtap.so] Error 1
```

I searched in my linuxbox to find libwiretap.so. It resides within /usr/lib. 
Can anyone direct me in order to resolve this error ! Thanks

Comment: I would guess you need to install the devel package(s) too; they have the necessary header files etc. Which packages that are depends on your distribution.

Comment: If the headers are missing the compiler complains, not the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `wireshark-devel`. It contains the headers for the wiretap library.